# How to count all if() instructions (Java)

Tags: search, if-statement, count

Is there any way to count all `if()` (or `else()`) instructions without using `BufferedReader` to search for distinguish words ? If there isn't - how can I guess if the `if()` instruction inside the /* comment:

```
/*
if(*condition*){
*do something*
}
*/
```

is just a comment, not an instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22760693/981828

What you are trying to achieve is far from trivial,

You would have to use a parser such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
or [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/)

edit:

alternativly you could run this perl one-liner from the command line, this should strip the file from all of its comments. If you are running windows, install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

```
perl -0pe 's#/\*(.|\n)*?\*/##g; s|//.*?\n|\n|g' test.java >> newfile.java
```

and then count if( and else( inside the newfile.java with a BufferedReader and [Tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking rather for Java way.